# Java switch statement says constant expression required even with case 1

Tags: java

I'm not sure the title is well written, but when I wrote switch statement,

```
switch(testMap.get(key).getValue()){
    case 1:
        //do something
}
```

It says constant expression required. This didn't change even if I changed it into

```
static final int CONSTANT = 1;

switch(testMap.get(key).getValue()){
    case CONSTANT:
        //do something
}
```

Even though I assume it shouldn't change much in the first place...

Updated on Map..

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Pair> testMap = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Pair>()
    .put("example1",new Pair(Object1, 1)).put("example2", new Pair(Object2,5)).build();
```

Comment: it's the Map.get(key) the compiler is complaining about

Comment: Both `case 1` and `case CONSTANT` usually work fine. Please post a [mcve]. In particular, what type is your map?

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/gfCtO6) - Please post a minimal complete example which demonstrates the issue

Comment: @Stultuske What makes you think that?

Comment: A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types, the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer. Type of Map.get(key) has to be one of those. Probably you have to use generics in your map declaration or explicitly cast result of get to one of those types.

Comment: @khelwood because it's none of the other two parts. both 1 and CONSTANT (second example) are valid

Comment: Are you trying to access to `Map` statically ? Could you try to declare your map with a lowercase and use it in your switch ?

Comment: What type is `Pair.getValue()` declared to return?

Comment: From what I see, you are using a `Pair<Object, Object>` (well, not really, it is a `Pair` but `pair.getValue()` will still return a `Object`) so it can't be used in a `switch`. Only primitive and `String` are accepted (based on the version of java)

Comment: @khelwood I think it returns Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Pair.getValue()` declares its return-type as `Object`, then the compiler is not going to know how to perform a switch on it. The compiler will only allow you to switch on an integral type or a string or an enum.

If you *know* it is going to be an integer, and you cast it to an `int`, the compiler will know it is possible to switch on it.

```
switch ((int) testMap.get(key).getValue()) {
    case 1: // do something
    // ...
}
```

Depending on the version of Java you are using, you might need to cast it to `Integer`.

Comment: I think it should be cast to Integer since it's Object type..? Cannot cast Object to int.

Comment: @CherylYang It worked with `(int)` when I tried it, but it might depend what version of Java you are using.